# nested fields_for not showing up in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything looks great as far as I can tell -- but the contents for the field_for nested form aren't displaying the 3 question forms I want. Why?

survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
end
```

surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  # GET /surveys/1
  # GET /surveys/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times { @survey.questions.build }
  end

  # GET /surveys/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /surveys
  # POST /surveys.json
  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1
  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.update(survey_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /surveys/1
  # DELETE /surveys/1.json
  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to surveys_url, notice: 'Survey was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

surveys/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Survey</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', surveys_path %>
```

surveys/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

    <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :content, "Question" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
  </p>
  <% end %> 



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't believe I did this -- was missing `<%=` on `fields_for`

Comment: Thanks for answering this one. I've been stuck on this for longer than I'd care to admit!

Comment: Thanks, 5 years later I, too, missed the `<%=` on `fields_for`.